How do I create a custom widget like this in Flutter?

I'm new to Flutter and need help creating a custom widget for displaying the credit score, credit score value will be getting from the API need to ping the value in UI. I am seeking guidance and references based on the attached screenshot; have checked over internet there is no any example to create UI like this but there is no luck.

There is no straight answer to this. You may want to check out the CustomPaint class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

I have made this for you specially. I made it to keep min max dynamic and on change post back. Now it's up to you to customize UI further using Custom Painter etc.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final double min;
  final double max;
  final Function(double) onValueChanged; // Postback function

  GradientSlider(
      {required this.min, required this.max, required this.onValueChanged});

  @override
  _GradientSliderState createState() => _GradientSliderState();
}

class _GradientSliderState extends State<GradientSlider> {
  double _sliderValue = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sliderValue = (widget.max + widget.min) /
        2; // Set initial value to the middle of the range
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent, // Keep the background transparent
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          // The custom slider widget
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 40),
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                double thumbWidth = 40; // Define the width of the thumb here
                double thumbHalfWidth = thumbWidth / 2;

                return Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      height: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 244, 109, 99),
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 177, 73),
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 241, 117),
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 111, 190, 255),
                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 190, 127),
                            ],
                          )),
                      child: Stack(children: [
                        DividerPainter(leftPercent: 50),
                        DividerPainter(leftPercent: 70),
                        DividerPainter(leftPercent: 85)
                      ]),
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        trackHeight: 25, // Height of the slider
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
                        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
                        thumbColor: Colors.transparent,
                        overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
                        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                          enabledThumbRadius: 0, // No radius for thumb
                          disabledThumbRadius: 0,
                        ),
                        overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                          overlayRadius: 0, // No overlay radius
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Slider(
                        value: _sliderValue,
                        min: widget.min,
                        max: widget.max,
                        divisions: 10,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _sliderValue = value;
                            widget.onValueChanged(
                                value); // Postback function called here
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Custom thumb widget positioned correctly
                    Positioned(
                      top: -2,
                      left: (_sliderValue - widget.min) /
                              (widget.max - widget.min) *
                              (constraints.maxWidth - thumbWidth) +
                          thumbHalfWidth,
                      child: CustomThumb(), // Your custom thumb widget
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          // The labels under the slider
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Spacer(
                  flex: 1,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.min.toInt().toString(), // Min label
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Handle overflow
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    ((widget.min + widget.max) / 2)
                        .toInt()
                        .toString(), // Middle label
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Handle overflow
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.max.toInt().toString(), // Max label
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Handle overflow
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Custom thumb widget
class CustomThumb extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
          size: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 7,
          height: 35,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 1.25,
              height: 35,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DividerPainter extends StatelessWidget {
  int leftPercent;
  DividerPainter({super.key, required this.leftPercent});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100) * (leftPercent - 10),
      top: -18,
      bottom: -18,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            width: 1.5,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

How it is looks like now:

These break-downs are also flexible so you can manage as per your desire.

I appreciate your prompt help. Now, I'm having trouble adding the shape to each vertical bar; any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated

i am not good at Custom Paint, but can make a smiller with some comon comps, do you still need ?

Yes, please I am still struggling

i have updated please check if this helps you please accept the answer

By the way, for this kind of effort, I charge bounties—just kidding! Haha!

This is an excellent effort Shoua, and I have no doubt that it will benefit others in the future. However it's worth considering that the OP will not ever learn something if they are spoon-fed. It is a hard balance to strike.
